# Difference between net35 and net35-client Facebook c# SDK

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

What is the difference between the dlls in net35 and net35-client folders of facebook c# sdk? which one I should use? In my application, I am using both the javascript and the server side coding.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the DLLs from both projects for a web site project. The client folder contains non-web related components and the other folder contains the web related components (e.g for Canvas access).